# How to pass webpack env into nodejs application?

Tags: node.js, webpack

I compile my nodejs application with webpack.

And I want to pass variable to my application say version.

so after I run this command:

```
webpack --env.VERSION=1.2.2
```

I run my application but I got undefined on `console.log({ v: process.env.VERSION });`.

How to pass webpack env into nodejs application?

I can't use `cross-env` or something like that. I want to compile with webpack and having the env variables in my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the docs for the `--env` flag ([here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/)):

> The webpack command line [environment option](https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/#environment-options) `--env` allows you to pass in as many environment variables as you like. Environment variables will be made accessible in your `webpack.config.js`.

You can use the `DefinePlugin` plugin to have webpack replace strings with the value of your environment variables.

For example, to replace the use of `process.env.VERSION` in your application code to the value of the environment variable you have set using the `--env` flag at build time:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    "process.env.VERSION": JSON.stringify(process.env.VERSION)
  })
]
```

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation on webpack, the env variable will be available in your `webpack.config.js` like this

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = env => {
  // Use env.<YOUR VARIABLE> here:
  console.log('NODE_ENV: ', env.NODE_ENV); // 'local'
  console.log('Production: ', env.production); // true

  return {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
  };
};
```

See here for more details :

https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/